# Pt-online-schema-change - Huge replication lag when renaming tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration, pt-online-schema-change

We are using ptosc on a Percona MySQL 5.7 database and at the end of the process we encounter a huge 2-3min replication lag on all replicas.

We are using the following command and it does pause the copying of data when it encounters a replication lag, but near the end of the process, presumably when renaming the table, we do get a huge replication lag.

This here is the command we are using:

```
pt-online-schema-change -u 'username' -p 'password' \
--max-lag 5 \
--max-load Threads_running=30 \
--critical-load Threads_running=200 \
--pause-file /tmp/pt-pause-file \
--alter-foreign-keys-method drop_swap  \
--alter "ADD COLUMN test TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL" \
--recurse 1 \
D=db,t=table
```

Comment: I would guess you have a long-running transaction holding a metadata lock on the table on the replica. This blocks the metadata lock request by the rename table. If you keep your transactions shorter, that will allow the rename to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We probably have found the issue. We are using the `drop_swap` method for foreign keys.

While the renaming goes through quite fast, it needs to wait for the table to be dropped, which takes some time on a big table. Therefore the whole "switching-over" process does take way longer.

For us the solution is too move away from FKs, and take the downtime into account when doing migrations on them.